Enquiry about Joint reactions for Unity 3D
I am working in unity since 2 years. I have few questions regarding hinge joint in unity3D. There is a member function reactionForce for Joint2D class. It helps in getting the joint reactions in unity 2D environment. Please find the relevant link here.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Joint2D-reactionForce.html#:~:text=When%20a%20joint%20tries%20to,Additional%20resources%3A%20GetReactionForce%2C%20breakForce.
The variable reactionForce stores the value of joint reactions in X and Y directions. My requirement is in 3D environment.
But is there a function that helps us getting in unity3D ? For example, I would like to calculate joint reactions for a hinge in 3D enviroment. Is it possible to calculate joint reactions?
Or does the same variable can be used for storing reactionForce.
Thanks in advance

The 3D counter part to Joint2D.reactionForce

When a joint tries to constrain a Rigidbody2D it may need to apply a force to do so. This is known as the reaction force.

is basically Joint.currentForce

The force applied by the solver to satisfy all constraints.

